Attachments not working in SharePoint List form customized powerapps
I have a SP list and the list form has be customized using the Powerapps.So, the poerapps form alos displays the attached files for the respective item. but when I try to click on the file over the form, it shows below information.
'The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:378274cd-e01e-000b-7df6-dc7073000000 Time:2024-07-23T11:51:10.5974799Z'
I am unable to understand why this is happening.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

On the Advanced Settings tab of the Attachments control, change the Value field to "AbsoluteUri".


With the default "Attachments" column added to the SharePoint PowerApps Form, could not reproduce the error as you've described . In my test for the Display Mode Form, was able to click the Attachments (pdf, docs, xlsx) and download and view the files in the corresponding client applications.
Could you describe more about the file types that you have used? Make sure that the attachments have not been deleted from the list items.

